# Exception in moving a file using moveFile method in common io using java

Tags: java, file-io, apache-commons

```
File source=new File(fname1);
System.out.println("souce name "+fname1);
File dest = new File("F:\\BackupFiles",source.getName());
try 
{
   FileUtils.moveFile(source, dest);
   source.delete();
} 
catch (IOException ex) 
{
Logger.getLogger(FileCompare.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
System.out.println("file moved successfully...");
```

the above code throws exception

```
"java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'C:\xampp\htdocs\eyeOS\eyeos\users\ajkani\files\html.txt' after copy to 'F:\BackupFiles\html.txt' "
```

and i tried to delete the file after copied it to the destination but unable to delete.

i tried `deleteOnExit()` method instead of `delete()` but nothing works.

i have used md5 algorithm to check the similarity of two files.
if the files are not same.i want to move the files to destination directory.

Comment: It seems that you don't have the `write` right.

Comment: Seems like your source file is locked by another process.

Comment: either you don't have sufficient permissions to delete the source file, or it's locked by some other process (maybe your previous java attempts, or some editor). I'd use a tool such as Unlocker to check for it.

Comment: please say the tool name to unlock.

Answer (score 0):

From above code, it seems that you want to move one file from one directory to another.
As per this assumption, you can use below code.

```
String sourcePath = "D:\\other\\new.xls";
File source = new File(sourcePath);
System.out.println("souce name " + sourcePath);
File destDirPath = new File("D:\\");

try {
     FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(source, destDirPath, false);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("file moved successfully...");
```

This will definitely help you.

Comment: even i tried this. but this throws an exception as failed to delete the original file after copying it to the destination folder.

Comment: Create new java class and paste this code in main method. Change the source file and destination directory path, then run it.
Share the code and exception after testing above code.

Comment: I can move the files for the same source and destination by executing in main method as a separate file. I think the file is already opened by some other process. how do i close it and move it successfully? please help me.

Comment: Whether the file you want to is on shared location?
If that file is on your machine, then restart your machine.
After this try your code.

Comment: I have identified the solution. Actually i have used FileInputStream in my program and i didn't close it. So, this problem arises.

Comment: It seems that you have not provided complete code here.