# How to upload file and copy the same file at destination in Play framework

Tags: java, file-io, playframework, path

I wanted to upload my file at one source and should copy the same file at another destination from that source in Play framework, below is my code and please let me know where I am doing wrong as it is giving error like: error: method move in class Files cannot be applied to given types;(The method move(Path, Path, CopyOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, StandardCopyOption).

```
public static Result upload()
    {
       MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        FilePart uploadedFile = body.getFile("file");
        if (uploadedFile != null) {
           String fileName = uploadedFile.getFilename();
           String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
           File file = uploadedFile.getFile();
           file.renameTo(new File("D:/images/" +fileName));// it can be source 
           java.nio.file.Files.move("D:/images/", "D:/images/files/", StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
          return ok("File is uploaded at source and copied the same file at destination");
       }
       else
       {         
           return badRequest("No file is uploaded.");
        }
     }
```

**html:**

```
@form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because java.nio.file.Files.move uses Path instead Strings:   java.nio.file.Files.move( **file.toPath()**, **newFile.toPath()**, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);

Other good alternative easy to read is `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(file, new File(path, fileName));` this example to [move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779928/exception-in-moving-a-file-using-movefile-method-in-common-io-using-java).

This code is not tested:

```
Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart uploadedFile = body.getFile("file");
if (uploadedFile != null) {
    String fileName = uploadedFile.getFilename();
    String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    File file = uploadedFile.getFile();
    file.renameTo(new File("D:/images/" +fileName));// it can be source

    File newFile = new File("D:/images/files/" + uploadedFile.getFilename());

    java.nio.file.Files.move( file.toPath(),newFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);

   // org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(file, new File(path, fileName));

    return ok("File is uploaded at source and copied the same file at destination");
}
```

Hope this may help

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried this, but I am getting error: Unexpected exception: RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.(IT is coming at:  java.nio.file.Files.move( file.toPath(),newFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);)